# Is there a way to stop the user from going 'outside' of my 'map'?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, keyerror

```
'd4': {
        ZONENAME : 'Kingdom Church',
        DESCRIPTION : 'description',
        EXAMINATION : 'examine',
        SOLVED : False,
        UP : 'c4',
        DOWN : '',
        LEFT : 'd3',
        RIGHT : ''
}
```

This dictionary (part of a nested dictionary) representing the 'map'. D4 is the last tile down and the last tile right. It seems I can't figure it out how to deal with the app crash when someone tries to go right or down when at location d4. I need something like this:

```
if myPlayer.location == 'd4' and zonemap['d4'][RIGHT = '']
   print("You can't go there!")
```

Some more code that may be helpful and may let u understand my project better:

```
def print_location():
    print('\n'+'#' + myPlayer.location.upper() + '#')
    print('#' + zonemap[myPlayer.location][DESCRIPTION] + '#' + '\n')
    
def prompt():
    print('================================')
    print('\n' + 'What would you like to do?')
    action = input('> ').lower()
    acceptable_actions = ['move', 'go', 'travel', 'walk', 'quit', 'examine', 'inspect', 'interact','look']
    while action not in acceptable_actions:
        print('Unknown action, please try again.\n')
        action = input('> ').lower()
    if action == 'quit':
        sys.exit()
    elif action in ['move', 'go', 'travel', 'walk']:
        player_move(action)
    elif action in ['examine', 'inspect', 'interact', 'look']:
        player_examine(action)

def player_move(myAction):
    ask = 'Where would you like to move to?\n> '
    dest = input(ask)
    if dest in ['up', 'north']:
        destination = zonemap[myPlayer.location][UP]
        movement_handler(destination)
    elif dest in ['left', 'west']:
        destination = zonemap[myPlayer.location][LEFT]
        movement_handler(destination)   
    elif dest in ['down', 'south']:
        destination = zonemap[myPlayer.location][DOWN]
        movement_handler(destination)
    elif dest in ['right', 'east']:
        destination = zonemap[myPlayer.location][RIGHT]
        movement_handler(destination)

def movement_handler(destination):
    myPlayer.location = destination
    print_location()
```

You have here the function that prints the location as A1 A2 etcetera and the description.
The function that prompts over and over as the main loop. Last but not least the player movement function and the movement handler.

Comment: Why do you not use "something like this"?

Comment: I can't figure out in what function to use it. When I am using it in the movement_handler function i get the following error:  line 262, in print_location
    print('#' + zonemap[myPlayer.location][DESCRIPTION] + '#' + '\n')
KeyError: ''

Comment: How about using it when the player is about to move?

Comment: When using it in the player_move function it gives me the same damn error

Comment: That sounds like a different problem.

Comment: Oh I see.  But is my "something like this" piece of code written correctly? I mean it does what I want to do or not. Maybe I can figure it out where to insert it.

Comment: Instead of `[RIGHT = '']` you probably meant `[RIGHT] = ''`.

Comment: Is it necessary to let the app crash there? Or can you just let your player run into a wall at the map edge by setting `DOWN : 'd4'` and `RIGHT : 'd4'` and not handling anything?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you already figured out what to do, but here is what I've would done.

```py
def player_move(myAction):
    ask = 'Where would you like to move to?\n> '
    dest = input(ask)
    direction = None
    if dest in ['up', 'north']:
        direction = UP
    elif dest in ['left', 'west']:
        direction = LEFT
    elif dest in ['down', 'south']:
        direction = DOWN
    elif dest in ['right', 'east']:
        direction = RIGHT
    if not direction:
        # you need to check if the correct direction was entered
        print ("ERROR wrong direction ... ")
        return
    if not zonemap[myPlayer.location][direction]:
        # You use empty string if player cannot go in direction so negation of empty string is True
        print ("You cannot go there")
        return
    mPlayer.location = zonemap[myPlayer.location][direction]
```

This way you cover all cases - UP/LEFT/DOWN/RIGHT with single check.